# Getting a question mark box on the end of my file extension, how to fix?

Tags: mac, file-corruption

I plugged in flash drive into my mac, and I've never had problems with these files before. Now there are these question mark box symbols on the end of the file extension (see screenshot for more details).  Some files are fine and work accordingly.  when I open the file, I keep getting this message that they're corrupted or decoded incorrectly, but when I plug it into a windows machine, it works fine.

I've tried deleting the question marks on the end of the extension, but I still get the corruption message. how do I fix this on my mac? currently on 12.0.1 - Monterey.

[image]

Comment: also tried this and didn't work: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7568999

Comment: Which file-format is the device? Have you modified the device using Windows? Also see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491441/17660).

Comment: First, update your OS as soon as possible. 12.0.1 was the bugfest from hell. Current version is 12.3, released this week. Secondly, it's not at all wise to use SD Cards, especially ones formatted as FAT32 to store data. FAT cannot hold correct file permissions or resources. [Reinstalling the OS is a common way to fix font corruption - you *might* just fix it with the update. Definitely worth a try before anything else.]

Comment: okay, I've updated my OS, and nothing.  I copied the files over to an external hard drive, and reformated the flash drive from FAT32 to an exFAT format.  I copied it again and it's still getting that question mark on the end.  I took a picture with my camera, and that jpg file readable now (before my images were getting the same question mark symbol on the end). Is it because I copied the files over from an ntsf harddrive?  Is there a way to encode the files to something readable?

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening. The Mac itself should be capable of reading/writing FAT32 & ExFAT perfectly well. It can also read but not write NTFS natively. It might be worth a shot at formatting it NTFS just to carry the data over, if you can't copy it across the network instead. I'd also be inclined to try a different card, in case there's something specifically wrong with that one.

Comment: this looks like the mac is showing the null-termination "character" for the filename(s). AFAIK Fat/NTFS/linux/unix use NULL to signal the end of a filename in the file table. Not sure why you'd see this though. Might be worth seeing if there is a terminal tool that can be used to emit what the shell thinks that char is. Bad codec using *n*-bytes to read, but *n* is inclusive of the null?